# C - how does passing space-separated strings to a single parameter work?

Tags: c, char

This is probably a very simple and core component of C programming but it's extremely hard to search for

printk in the kernel can take a number of log level consts and the function itself uses varargs, however I can't figure out why it works. Here's an example call for those not familiar

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "this is my message which can be %s as normal", "formatted");
```

The source code is below and it uses varargs but what mechanism allows to pass multiple strings that are space-separated to one parameter?

```
asmlinkage __visible int printk(const char *fmt, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        int r;

        va_start(args, fmt);
        r = vprintk_func(fmt, args);
        va_end(args);

        return r;
}
```

This isn't particular to printk, I've seen it used in drivers in the kernel when creating a device

```
device_create(drv_class, 
                      NULL,    
                      dev, 
                      NULL,      
                      MY_DEVICE_NAME "%d", i);
```

Can anyone tell me what allows this? Is it compiler specific or a core part of the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("hello World\n");
// or equivalent
printf("h" "e" "l" "l" "o" " " "W" "o" "r" "l" "d" "\n");
// or equivalent
#define char_h "h"
printf(char_h "ello World\n");
```

String literals are concatenated together. That means, that `"ab"` and `"a" "b"` is the same. The null termination character is added on the end only.

The preprocessor substitutes only. So [`#define KERN_DEBUG "<7>"`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.2/source/include/linux/printk.h#L16) just makes preprocessor substitute `KERN_DEBUG` for `"<7>"`.

Then after preprocessor two string literals are concatened. So for example `printf(KERN_DEBUG "...");` becomes `printf("<7>" "...");` and then string literals are concatenated into `printf("<7>...");`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a C language feature that concatenates string literals at compile time. `"foo" "bar"` is equivalent to `"foobar"`. It's very convenient for putting long strings in code but can also be used together with macro expansion. Consider:

```
#define FOO "foo"
int i;
printf(FOO "%d", i);
```

This is just passing `"FOO" "%d"` to `printf`, which is equivalent to `"FOO%d"` as a result of macro expansion and the C language rules for string constants.

Comment: Am I missing something with the first example or did you miss the KERN_DEBUG? I thought they were exactly the same mechanism. I was just showing that it otherwise works per printf using the varargs with the %

Comment: Oh, I missed that! Thanks, that makes my answer *much* simpler.